# How to convert a range of cells values to a row of values in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheets, I have a range of cells, say A1:D6,  I am to using importrange function to grab this range to another sheet.
My requirement is to populate this data into one row A1:A24 (24 elements).

Is there a function for doing this in google sheets?

Thanks in Advance,

Vijay

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flatten()`, like this:

```
=transpose( flatten( importrange("...", "Sheet1!A1:D6") ) )
```

If you are copying data from one tab to another within the *same spreadsheet file*, do not use `importrange()` but a regular cross-sheet reference, like this:

```
=transpose(flatten(Sheet1!A1:D6))
```